# Is there a Sharepoint URL link which shows all accessible sites for a user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-site

Im wondering if there is URL in Sharepoint O365, which gives to a standard O365 user (NOT and admin) an view / list of all websites, on which the user has access.

At the moment, if the user opens the sharepoint in O365 it displays 3 categroies:

1. News from Websites
2. Frequent websites
3. Suggested websites

These 3 categories do have some of the websites, but not all. Because there is a limit of displaying a website. 
So that's why im asking this question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question but for those who are looking for the answer. You can type `contentclass:STS_Site` in the search box of the SharePoint Home Page to get all sites you have access to. In order to get subsites too, type `contentclass:STS_Site OR contentclass:STS_Web`.

Thus, a SharePoint URL that gives you the sites collections and subsites you have access to would be `https://[your_tenant].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx?q=contentclass%3ASTS_Site%20OR%20contentclass%3ASTS_Web&v=%2Fsearch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot chestacio!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't think anything like that exists, since permissions are attributes of content and not of the user itself. You would have to construct such a list yourself.

So you can only see all users that are eligible to visit the News Site (the top permission button)

Perhaps this is useful for you: Under Site-Setting -> Site-Permissions click on the button "check permission". You can enter a user and you will get a list of everything that modified your base permission. Perhaps you can extract the information from that.